# MSYS: alias resets upon restarting MSYS console

Tags: alias, msys

Every time I reopen the **MSYS** console (not cmd.exe) I find that the aliases that I have added to the shell are cleared. How can I save my aliases so that I do not to reenter them on every use?

For example:

```
$ alias desktop="cd=C:/Users/Superuser/Desktop"
$ alias
clear='clsb'
desktop='cd=C:/Users/Superuser/Desktop'
```

Upon restarting:

```
$ alias
clear='clsb'
```

How can I preserve my aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to user directory:

```
cd ~
```

Append to .bash_profile (which will run upon every new bash session):

```
echo "alias desktop=\"cd=C:/Users/Superuser/Desktop\"" >> .bash_profile
```

Warning! Some versions of msys uses .profile for aliases.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the MSYS console, but doing the following works in minTTy.

Open your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile`) file in a good text editor. Scroll to the bottom. After the line `alias clear=clsb`, add

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

This way, you get to keep your aliases in a separate file while still having them load every time you start your Console or terminal emulator.